# How can I switch two Bootstrap divs that stack to different columns?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm very sorry if this is a dumb question! I'm still fairly new to Bootstrap.

I have 4 divs. On md and lg screens I'm going for this:

```
[A] [B] [C] [D]
```

On sm screens I want to reorder to two columns. The code I have does this:

```
[A] [B]
[C] [D]
```

BUT, what I really **want** it to do is this:

```
[A] [C]
[B] [D]
```

Then, on xs screens I want it to do this:

```
[A]
[B]
[C]
[D]
```

How do I accomplish that with Bootstrap? I know there are classes to push and pull, but I haven't figured out how they work -- when I try to push and pull the middle divs, they end up disappearing. I would really appreciate your help!

By the way, here is the code I've got now:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
      <div class="container centered">
          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
              A
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
              B
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
              C
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
              D
          </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.col-md-push-` and `.col-md-pull-` to change the order of your columns.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working for me -- when I push B and pull C, it ends up layering the columns over top of one another.

Answer (score 0):

**Push** is in CSS **left: x%** and **pull** is in CSS **right: x%**. I think, the divs disappear, because they are **too far away** or they are **at the same place**.

I think, in this case you can't work with pull and push.

If you want it to do with the complete alphabet, you have to use **position absolute** in sm for every col.

For A - M stay on the left with `left: 0`. And for N - Z stay on the right with `right: 0`. You can change *0* to another value. And you have to give each col in sm a `top`. Otherwise it doesn't work.

***CSS***

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px) {
    .alpha > .row > div {
        position: absolute;
    }
    .left-sm {
        left: 0;
    }
    .right-sm {
        right: 0;
    }
    /* left side */
    .alpha > .row:nth-of-type(1) > div:nth-of-type(1) {
        top: 0px; /* A */
    }
    .alpha > .row:nth-of-type(1) > div:nth-of-type(2) {
        top: 50px; /* B */
    }
    .alpha > .row:nth-of-type(1) > div:nth-of-type(3) {
        top: 100px; /* ... */
    }
    .alpha > .row:nth-of-type(1) > div:nth-of-type(4) {
        top: 150px;
    }
    .alpha > .row:nth-of-type(2) > div:nth-of-type(1) {
        top: 200px;
    }
    .alpha > .row:nth-of-type(2) > div:nth-of-type(2) {
        top: 250px;
    }
    .alpha > .row:nth-of-type(2) > div:nth-of-type(3) {
        top: 300px;
    }
    .alpha > .row:nth-of-type(2) > div:nth-of-type(4) {
        top: 350px;
    }
    .alpha > .row:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(1) {
        top: 400px;
    }
    .alpha > .row:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(2) {
        top: 450px;
    }
    .alpha > .row:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) {
        top: 500px;
    }
    .alpha > .row:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(4) {
        top: 550px;
    }
    .alpha > .row:nth-of-type(4) > div:nth-of-type(1) {
        top: 600px;
    }
    /* right side */
    .alpha > .row:nth-of-type(4) > div:nth-of-type(2) {
        top: 0px; /* N */
    }
    .alpha > .row:nth-of-type(4) > div:nth-of-type(3) {
        top: 50px; /* O */
    }
    .alpha > .row:nth-of-type(4) > div:nth-of-type(4) {
        top: 100px; /* ... */
    }
    .alpha > .row:nth-of-type(5) > div:nth-of-type(1) {
        top: 150px;
    }
    .alpha > .row:nth-of-type(5) > div:nth-of-type(2) {
        top: 200px;
    }
    .alpha > .row:nth-of-type(5) > div:nth-of-type(3) {
        top: 250px;
    }
    .alpha > .row:nth-of-type(5) > div:nth-of-type(4) {
        top: 300px;
    }
    .alpha > .row:nth-of-type(6) > div:nth-of-type(1) {
        top: 350px;
    }
    .alpha > .row:nth-of-type(6) > div:nth-of-type(2) {
        top: 400px;
    }
    .alpha > .row:nth-of-type(6) > div:nth-of-type(3) {
        top: 450px;
    }
    .alpha > .row:nth-of-type(6) > div:nth-of-type(4) {
        top: 500px;
    }
    .alpha > .row:nth-of-type(7) > div:nth-of-type(1) {
        top: 550px;
    }
    .alpha > .row:nth-of-type(7) > div:nth-of-type(2) {
        top: 600px;
    }
}
```

***HTML***

```
<div class="container alpha">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 left-sm">
            <div class="space well">A</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 left-sm">
            <div class="space well">B</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 left-sm">
            <div class="space well">C</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 left-sm">
            <div class="space well">D</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 left-sm">
            <div class="space well">E</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 left-sm">
            <div class="space well">F</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 left-sm">
            <div class="space well">G</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 left-sm">
            <div class="space well">H</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 left-sm">
            <div class="space well">I</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 left-sm">
            <div class="space well">J</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 left-sm">
            <div class="space well">K</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 left-sm">
            <div class="space well">L</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 left-sm">
            <div class="space well">M</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 right-sm">
            <div class="space well">N</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 right-sm">
            <div class="space well">O</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 right-sm">
            <div class="space well">P</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 right-sm">
            <div class="space well">Q</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 right-sm">
            <div class="space well">R</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 right-sm">
            <div class="space well">S</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 right-sm">
            <div class="space well">T</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 right-sm">
            <div class="space well">U</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 right-sm">
            <div class="space well">V</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 right-sm">
            <div class="space well">W</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 right-sm">
            <div class="space well">X</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 right-sm">
            <div class="space well">Y</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 right-sm">
            <div class="space well">Z</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/PeterLeger/owwvubun/1/embedded/result/)

Comment: This works! My only concern is that there is a decent amount of content in each of these divs (it is a bunch of linked buttons for the 50 states, which is why the order matters -- alphabetical) and I don't want to upset Google/my SEO by hiding lots of content from the visitor.

Comment: I've updated my answer. If you want to do it with the complete alphabet, it is another case! Please update your question so that one can know that it is about the complete alphabet. Thank you very much!